# NoSuchMethodError WSDLReader.readWSDL in JBPM WorkItemHandler

Tags: web-services, jbpm, business-process-management

I'm working with JBPM 5.4 and using the console-server rest services available to manage the workflow of the processes.

I've also successfully tested a dummy WorkItemHandler that just get 2 values and return the sum of them, just to see a simple process working.
That was fine.

However, as I was testing a **WorkItemHandler to invoke a external Web Service**, the following error appeared:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:237) [cxf-rt-core-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:186) [cxf-rt-core-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
```

**What I did:**

I used the **cxf-codegen-plugin version 2.4.4**  *(wich is the same version of cxf in the lib of console-server.war)* to generate the java code from a wsdl.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/adm/exampleService.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The code is generated just fine.

I copied the work item jar file in the lib folder of the console-server project, as I have done before with a dummy WorkItemHandler.

I have also checked the cxf(2.4.4) and wsdl4j(1.6.2) versions inside de lib folder of console-server project. In fact, WSDLReader contains the "missing" method in that jar version of wsdl4j.

**Where I am:**

I understand that somehow the class called it is not from that version, but I can't imagine how that happens.

Anyone have a clue what to do?

I'm using the jboss that comes with jbpm installer, I have changed nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I will document here in case someone stumbles accross this in the future:

JBPM 5.4 - Project gwt-console-server.war
Inside the lib folder there are these 2 jars:
wsdl4j.jar and javax.wsdl_1.5.1.v201012040544.jar.

They have the same classes, but inside the second jar, as it is another version, the class doesnt have the method required.

So, I simply removed that jar. I imagine it is a mistake for both of them to be together, but if someone knows a reason and I will fall in another issue further, please let me know. For now, it solves the problem.

Anyway, thanks everyone for the attention, I was struggling for a while with this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that, if you do have a jar with the correct version of WSDLReader in your classpath, that you might have another jar in your classpath that also contains an (incorrect) version of the same class.  Note that this might be in your own war, but for example also in the server lib folder etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. The jboss only contains the wars that comes with the jbpm installer + the my workitemhandler jar inside console-server war lib folder. Do you think the jboss that comes with the installer contains any other version of wsdl4j? I looked inside the server, but no look. I will continue looking. If you remember something let me know.

Comment: Kris, here is something that I found, inside of the gwt-console-server lib folder there 2 jars with the same class. One wsdl4j(which contains the method that is called) and other javax.wsdl_1.5.1.v201012040544.jar (that does not contains). Do you know why they are together? I will remove it anyway and see if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude the wsdl4j.jar dependency in your pom file.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>axis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as the same class is found in two jar files. You can check the same in your local workspace to find in which jar files "javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader" class is present. Then keep only relevant jar file in your classpath.
In my case this file was present in given below two jar files:

1. eclipse-birt-javax.wsdl_1.5.1.v201012040544.jar
2. wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar

Hence I removed the irrelevant eclipse-birt-javax.wsdl_1.5.1.v201012040544.jar from classpath and then it worked.